# meta refresh html tag accessibility error

Tags: html

I'm running accessibility tests on my site with mauve wcag2.1 AAA and am getting this error: SC 3.2.5 - Tech H76 [WCAG 2.1 (AAA)]Using meta refresh to create an instant client-side redirect
reference link to the error:https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H76

but in the code I can't find any meta refresh. Reports me with that error these meta tags:

```
<meta name="robots" content="max-image-preview:large">
<meta content="Divi Child v.1.0.0" name="generator">
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 6.1.1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
<meta name="tec-api-version" content="v1">
<meta name="tec-api-origin" content="https://test.domain.it">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=1">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://test.domain.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/cropped-favicon-270x270.png">
```

while instead it does not report these to me as an error:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

the site is made with wordpress and with the divi theme, from what i understand i should take off the meta refresh, but i can't find it anywhere, could it be a false positive or is there really an error? how could I go about solving it if this error really existed?

Comment: When viewing the source code, is it the code generated by the server, or by the client? Possible the meta tag is being added by JavaScript on the client.